# Function arguments and how they work

Tags: javascript, function

I'm just trying to get a better understanding/confirmation of function arguments
In the function seen here:

```
function newFunction(data, status){
```

would the function apply specifically to data and status variables?

I don't quite understand how the arguments work.

Comment: I think you need more context .. there is no jQuery in your question, but JavaScript functions work just like subroutines in most programming languages do.

Comment: This sounds like more of a general programming question. Nothing specific to JavaScript or jQuery here...

Comment: @elclanrs It's more of a "didn't read a tutorial/book" situation .. (but no, it's not general programming because that is so basic and then there are some JavaScript-specific rules beyond any form of "unified" function-application operation which itself can vary greatly)

Comment: @pst Well.. I did read the tutorial.. it's just that anonymous functions were so commonly used up until this point. now it's a bit hard to find exactly where functions were introduced to see exactly what they said about it

Comment: @BrantBarton For reference: all functions in JavaScript work the same way - that is, a *function-object* is invoked. That is, the expression `fn(a,b,..)` first *evaluates* `fn` to a *function-object* and then applies ("calls") said function-object with the appropriate context and supplied arguments. It's the exact same mechanism as anonymous functions. (Consider "TypeError: .. is not a function" when `fn` does not evaluate to a function-object.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic Scenario**

When a function is defined, the `()` area is used for inputs. These inputs are mapped to what data is sent in.

```
function newFunction(data, status){
}
newFunction(1,2);
```

In this scenario, `data` will be assigned the value of `1`, and `status` will be assigned the value of `2` for the scope of `newFunction`.

**Missmatched inputs**

However, it does not always directly map. If fewer arguments are sent, then the unassigned input variables become `undefined`.

```
function newFunction(data, status){
}
newFunction(1);
```

In this scenario, `data` will be assigned the value of `1`, and `status` will be assigned the value of `undefined` for the scope of `newFunction`.

**arguments object**

Inside of the scope of `newFunction`, there is also access to the array like object called **[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)**.

```
function newFunction(data, status)
{
 var args = arguments;
}
newFunction(1);
```

In this scenario, the variable `args` will hold the `arguments` object. There you can check `args.length` to see that only 1 argument was sent. `args[0]` will give you that argument value, being `1` in this case.

**Function object**

A function can be made into an object with the `new` keyword. By using the `new` keyword on a function, a Function object is made. Once the Function object is made, `this` may be used to refer to the current Function object instead of the global window.

```
function newFunction(data,status){
 if( this instanceof newFunction ){
  //use as a Function object
  this.data = data;
 }else{
  //use as a normal function
 }
}
var myNewFunction = new newFunction(1);
```

In this scenario, `myNewFunction` now holds a reference to a Function object, and can be accessed as an object through dot notation or indexing. `myNewFunction["data"]` and `myNewFunction.data` now both hold the value of 1.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the function **accepts** both `data` and `status` parameters.  The programmer calling the funciton (you) is required for providing the parameters when calling the function (also known as **arguments**.)

Let's look at a simplified example:

```
function add(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

The function here takes two numbers, adds them together, and returns the result.  Now, as a programmer, you have the benefit of adding two numbers whenever you want without having to duplicate the functionality or copy/paste whenever you need your application to perform the same functionality.

Best of all, another programmer you work with can add two numbers together without worrying about how to do it, they can just call your function.

**EDIT:** Calling the function works as follows

```
var num1 = 10;
var num2 = 15;
var z = add(num1, num2); //z = 25
```

Comment: ...or it should do. It doesn't have to if it doesn't want to!

Comment: @RobertGrenier so these variables are created here and undefined presently?

Comment: @pst so basically this step just creates a variable, and then I can uses/define it within the function, yes?

Comment: I think you're asking about scope: read [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) for a nice answer.

Comment: Nit: parameters are what appear in a function declaration and can be used like variables from within the function body; arguments are the actual values (fsvo) that are passed to the function

Comment: @pst thank you.. THAT answered my question.. I thought they were called paramaters, but then saw something else that made me doubt it.

Comment: @RobertGreiner it might be clearer to give the parameters different variable names than the calling arguments, to clarify the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
function newFunction(data, status){ ... function code ... }
```

This is the Javascript definition of a function called newFunction.
You can pass arguments to a function. These are variables, either numbers or strings, with which the function is supposed to do something.
Of course the function behaviour/output depends on the arguments you give it.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/function.html